# Is it a bad idea to not use module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use browserify which enables me to include nodejs modules in my javascript files, which can then be used by the browser.
If I write my own js file and require it like so (in functions.js):

```
require('./_menu');
```

and here is that menu file:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $(".js-navigation").addClass("navigation--nav-color-two");
    } else {
        $(".js-navigation").removeClass("navigation--nav-color-two");
    }
});
```

Then you will notice I haven't used module.exports and everything still works with no problems. If I use module.exports, then everything continues to work in the same way. Is there any point therefore in using module.exports here? Or would I just want to do it in a larger file with lots of different functions available?

Comment: And why are you writing jQuery with very specific browser events in Node ?

Comment: ^^^^ Have you ever heard of Browserify?

Comment: all the javascript files get compiled into one functions.js file

Comment: without it, think of the require as "void" whereas with it, there's a "return".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't exporting anything....so no, it's not a bad idea.

Generally, you only use `module.exports` if you are creating a reusable piece of code in a separate file, e.g.:

```
    //MyClass.js
    var MyClass = function() {

    };

    MyClass.prototype.methodOne = function() {

    };

    module.exports = MyClass;

    //main.js
    var MyClass = require('MyClass.js');
    var myInstance = new MyClass();

     myInstance.methodOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly , maybe change your code like this :

```
var $ = require('jquery');

module.exports  = function(window){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 100) {
            $(".js-navigation").addClass("navigation--nav-color-two");
        } else {
            $(".js-navigation").removeClass("navigation--nav-color-two");
        }
    });
}
```

when you want to require it :

```
var scroll = require('./_menu');
scroll(window);
```